# parsing result from get request

Tags: python, json

i have the following code

```
from requests import session

payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'id': 'xxxxxxx',
    'password': 'xxxxxxx'
}

with session() as c:
    c.post('https://www.yalehomesystem.co.uk/homeportal/api/login/check_login', data=payload)
    response = c.get('https://www.yalehomesystem.co.uk/homeportal/api/panel/get_panel_mode')
    print(response.text)
```

which returns the following response

```
{"result":"1","message":[{"area":"1","mode":"disarm"}],"code":""}
```

how do i return just the mode? (which is "disarm")

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function from the `json` module to parse the string into a dictionary and then index as required:

```
import json
print(json.loads(response.text)['message'][0]['mode'])
#'disarm'
```

Comment: @Phairplay No problem